# Partial Derivative Stickler.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am having trouble with a question with partial derivatives.

Here is the question:

> Let $\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$
>
> Show that $$\frac{\partial ^2\rho}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2\rho}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial ^2\rho}{\partial z^2} = \frac{2}{\rho}$$

All I am getting is that the LHS is equal to O.

A square root is something to the power of 0.5
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho &=& \left(x^2\right)^{1/2} + \left(y^2\right)^{1/2} + \left(z^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&=&x^1 + y^1 + z^1\\
&=& x + y + z.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Therefore,
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z} = 1
$$

Furthermore, 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial z^2} = 0
$$

But this isn't equal to $2/ \rho$.

Any help here is appreciated. Apologies for the bad formatting. I don't know how to make it any nicer.

Comment: See my editing, use that as a reference to edit the rest part.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is not the same as $x+y+z$. Try it with $(x,y,z)=(3,4,12)$ if you don't believe me.

Comment: I suppose that $\rho$ is $P$. If this is the case, please edit.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I was thinking that when editing. But I only edit the text with format not put my own thoughts and possibly change the question :/. It should be edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = \frac{x}{\rho} \tag{*}
$$
similarly for the other derivatives
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y} &=& \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = \frac{y}{\rho},\\
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z} &=& \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = \frac{z}{\rho}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

then taking the second derivative for the x. We use the previous result from Eq. (*) as follows
$$
\frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{x}{\rho}\right)
$$
this leads to
$$
\frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{\rho} - \frac{x}{\rho^2}\frac{x}{\rho} = \frac{1}{\rho} - \frac{x^2}{\rho^3}.
$$
similary we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial y^2} &=& \frac{1}{\rho} - \frac{y^2}{\rho^3},\\
\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial z^2} &=& \frac{1}{\rho} - \frac{z^2}{\rho^3}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
all together
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial z^2} &=& \frac{3}{\rho} - \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{\rho^3}\\
&=& \frac{3}{\rho}-\frac{\rho^2}{\rho^3}\\
&=& \frac{3}{\rho}-\frac{1}{\rho} = \frac{2}{\rho}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: I tried it myself via the chain rule and I can't see how you got p as the denominator. Can you explain the differentiation again please?

Comment: Now that is a rather open question ;). But yeah sure go for it.

Comment: Very sorry! I can see my mistake! I wrote it wrong on the page. Thanks a lot for all your help. It is very much appreciated!

Comment: No worries :). Also modify your original question by subbing P for "\rho". Also take a look at how the mathjax looks in the revised edits.